# Node JS for loop inserting data twice

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying import the contacts in a database but sometime its inserting records 2 times. Requirement is, If the number is already exist it should get updated otherwise inserted as a new row. I am using MySQL database.

I am using for loop with async.

```
var numbers = {
    numbers:[
        {
            name:"A",
            number:9876543211
        },
        {
            name:"B",
            number:7876543211
        },
        {
            name:"C",
            number:9886543211
        },
        {
            name:"D",
            number:8876543211
        }
    ]
};
async.forEachOf(numbers, (numberObj, key, callback) => {
    var createdAt = moment.utc().valueOf();
    var updatedAt = moment.utc().valueOf();
        gfs.checkContact(userInfo.user_id, code, numberObj.number, function(contactInfo, err){
        if(err){
            response.error = "sorry";
            res.send(response); return false;
        }else{
            if (contactInfo.length > 0) {
                gfs.qry("UPDATE contacts SET fullName='"+numberObj.name+"', updatedAt='"+updatedAt+"' WHERE cid='"+contactInfo[0].cid+"'").then(function (results){
                }).catch(function (errorMessage){
                })
            }else{
                gfs.qry("INSERT INTO contacts(user_id, fullName, code, mobile, createdAt, updatedAt) VALUES('"+userInfo.user_id+"', '"+numberObj.name+"', '"+code+"', '"+numberObj.number+"', '"+createdAt+"', '"+updatedAt+"')").then(function (results){
                }).catch(function (errorMessage){
                })
            }
        }
            callback();
        });
    }, err => {
    if (err){
        response.error = "sorry";
        res.send(response);
    }else{
        response.success = "success";
        response.numbers = numbers;
        res.send(response);
    }
});
```

I want to insert the contact number if it's not exist in the database for logged-in user id or it should get update the other fields like name, updated at if number already in database for the logged-in user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code, now using promise. It's working fine now.

var numbers = [

```
{

    name:"A",

    number:9876543211

},

{

    name:"B",

    number:7876543211

},

{

    name:"C",

    number:9886543211

},

{

    name:"D",

    number:8876543211

}
```

];

async.forEachOf(numbers, (numberObj, key, callback) => {

```
var createdAt = moment.utc().valueOf();

var updatedAt = moment.utc().valueOf();

gfs.checkContactPromise({

    user_id:userInfo.user_id,

    code:code,

    mobile:numberObj.number,

    fullName:numberObj.name,

    createdAt:createdAt,

    updatedAt:updatedAt

}).then( function (addContactQry){

    gfs.qry(addContactQry).then(function (results){

        userContacts.push("'"+numberObj.number+"'");

        callback();

    }).catch(function (errorMessage){

        callback();

    })

}).catch( function (errorMessage){

    callback();

});
```

}, err => {

```
if (err){

    response.error = "sorry";

    res.send(response);

}else{

    response.success = "success";

    response.numbers = numbers;

    res.send(response);

}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

The `callback` needs to be inside the `.then`s or `.catch`es.

```
async.forEachOf(numbers, (numberObj, key, callback) => {
  var createdAt = moment.utc().valueOf();
  var updatedAt = moment.utc().valueOf();
  gfs.checkContact(userInfo.user_id, code, numberObj.number, function (contactInfo, err) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    } else {
      if (contactInfo.length > 0) {
        gfs.qry("UPDATE contacts SET fullName='" + numberObj.name + "', updatedAt='" + updatedAt + "' WHERE cid='" + contactInfo[0].cid + "'")
          .then(function (results) {
            return callback(null, true);
          }).catch(function (errorMessage) {
            return callback(errorMessage);
          })
      } else {
        gfs.qry("INSERT INTO contacts(user_id, fullName, code, mobile, createdAt, updatedAt) VALUES('" + userInfo.user_id + "', '" + numberObj.name + "', '" + code + "', '" + numberObj.number + "', '" + createdAt + "', '" + updatedAt + "')")
          .then(function (results) {
            return callback(null, true);
          }).catch(function (errorMessage) {
            return callback(errorMessage);
          })
      }
    }
  });
}, err => {
  if (err) {
    response.error = "sorry";
    res.send(response);
  } else {
    response.success = "success";
    response.numbers = numbers;
    res.send(response);
  }
});
```

**Note**: in your function `gfs.checkContact` the callback signature is `(contactInfo, err)`. Which is reverse of what Node.js standard. Node uses `err, callback` or `err, data`.

**EDIT1:**

Also, `.forEachOf` iterates object like `Object.keys`. In your case there is only one key called `numbers`.

So, the `numberObj` will contain:

```
[ { name: 'A', number: 9876543211 },
  { name: 'B', number: 7876543211 },
  { name: 'C', number: 9886543211 },
  { name: 'D', number: 8876543211 } ]
```

And `numberObj.name` will be `undefined`.

You probably want

```
async.each(numbers.numbers, ...)
```

Comment: Now I am getting same entry 9 times.

Comment: Edited the answer, check if helps you.

Comment: I made it correct, posted a new answer, please check.